# Arraylist Intersection performance (in time and space ) in Java

Tags: java, performance, out-of-memory, time-complexity, space-complexity

I need to make million of intersections of ArrayList in java, and for this purpose I use this method:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> intersection(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b) {
        Set<Integer> aSet = new HashSet<Integer>(a);
        Set<Integer> bSet = new HashSet<Integer>(b);

        for(Iterator<Integer> it = aSet.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            if(!bSet.contains(it.next())) it.remove();
        }
        return new ArrayList<Integer>(aSet);
    }
```

In terms of time It's performant But I have a lot of memory leaks and I often go out of memory. How can I improve the function in order to be performant both in time and in space?

**UPDATE**

The arraylists given in input must remain unchanged.

Comment: Why not use `removeAll()`?

Comment: WHy lists to start with and not `Set`s? And `Set` has `.retainAll()`

Comment: `removeAll()` is the best option if you do not want to write the code yourself.

Comment: While it is true that `removeAll` is better than repeatedly doing `remove` in a loop, the `retainAll` method in the `Set` class is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: He wants to do an intersection, not remove all values from one list to another. `retainAll()` seems to be a good way to do that. Also, if you want to use collections often, I'd suggest you use Guava, with have a lot of useful methods. For example `Sets.intersection(set1, set2)`

Comment: Are you using `Integer` as example or are you really using it in the working code?

Comment: retainAll seems not to be performant, see my comment in the first answer. 
@OlegEstekhin: I'm using integer also in the working code.

Comment: If there are real optimizations to be made, it's in handling multiple intersections at once. Under what conditions are you doing the intersections? Are you just intersecting every pair of arrays in a list of thousands of arrays or something? Do you know what intersections need done ahead of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution (for performance) would be to use a [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) like so

```
public static List<Integer> intersection2(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    SortedSet<Integer> aSet = new TreeSet<Integer>(a);
    aSet.retainAll(b);
    return new ArrayList<Integer>(aSet);
}
```

Another solution (for space) would be use the passed in List(s) like so (**EDITED** with the "new requirement" that the passed in List(s) be unchanged),

```
public static List<Integer> intersection3(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    List<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>(a); // <-- new requirement.
    c.retainAll(b);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Good advices. Sets are indeed better suited for that kind of things

Comment: I've tested your method with this code (http://pastebin.com/j0La75my) but it is performant only with little arraylists. These are the results: http://pastebin.com/L1RCPqLG .I've also noticed that your second method returns wrong results.

Comment: @IvanZandonà That isn't a [robust](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-benchmark1/index.html) benchmark.

Comment: I had never thought about the robustness of the benchmark. However, I have tried to insert your code in my application and performance plummeted considerably. I have tried the Guava library and would seem to be the solution at a little cost of time performance!

Answer (score 0):

First of you do not need to `HashSets` here , you can do this with a single `HashSet`.

Add everything from first `ArrayList` to a `HashSet` and , iterate through second 'ArrayList' and check if each element contained in the `HashSet` constructed earlier, if so add it to the result `ArrayList`.